# Building a network of trancievers at long distance

Tags: microcontroller, communication, wireless, network

I have a task to build a wireless network consisting of devices (based on microcontrollers), which transmit data to the main unit.

The devices must be located in an open space on the field with ~2 km between each other, to record and process the data from the sensors and transmit the processed data to the main unit. The devices transmit data when some events take place(very rare) and the size of the data is about 50-150 bytes.

The network must have a mesh topology, so every device should also be a repeater.

[image: estimated location]

So the question is, what technology and protocol are more appropriate for building this network with the specified spacing present between devices?

Comment: So you want a list of all possible technologies? Which have you researched so far, and what do you find lacking?

Comment: At this time i find ONE-NET open-source protocol (one-net.info), which is appropriate for my task, but the project seems dead.

Zig-bee it also seems suitable, but a distance between devices for this protocol is about 100 meter in an open space that is too short for me.
Can you suggest something else?

Comment: How are these devices powered?

Comment: Main unit has a stationary power, other devices powered by accumulators

Comment: You might want to look at Dust networks; I have used it a little but not at that range. The nice thing is they are easy to use. http://www.linear.com/products/wireless_sensor_networks_-_dust_networks

Comment: Why **must** the network have a mesh topology?

Comment: @Sylvain usually it's because the range of the whole network far exceeds the max range of any single unit, so a mesh topology with routing/multi-hop messages and re-broadcasting works very well. If you have a proper mesh and not just a single chain, it also has built-in redundancy and if a single unit fails you don't lose communication with every down-stream node.

Comment: @Igor1488 the Zigbee protocol using the "Xbee Pro" modules with external high gain antenna can go kilometers in open space, not just 100m.

Comment: [APRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Packet_Reporting_System)

Comment: But external high gain antennas are directional and not useful for transmission to several modules in different directions.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on something similar and I am using silicon lab's Flex Gecko. They offer a range of Sub-Ghz modules with integrated ARM cortex mcu which would be perfect for what you want.

They have a system called "Connect Stack" which allows you to create a network of wireless devices like the one you want in a few simple clicks within their IDE.

[image]

Every parameter is customizable and they also offer the RAIL API if you want to do something more custom than what the connect stack offers.

check it out : [connect networking stack](http://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/connect-networking-stack)
(Their dev kits are also pretty awesome)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [LoRa modules from Microchip](http://www.microchip.com/design-centers/wireless-connectivity/embedded-wireless/lora-technology). Even though they don't work in a mesh topology they should have enough range for your needs. Interfacing to an MCU is easy, they talk a simple serial protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the Low power RF solutions from TI.[This](http://www.ti.com/lit/wp/swry006/swry006.pdf?DCMP=longrange&HQS=ep-wcs-lprf-longrange-conw-20151204-whip-narrwoband-wwe) type of solution can cover upto 25Kms but with low throughput.I assume sine you don't intent to transfer much data this TI based solution should be feasible for you.